# Get the issuing CA for a given certificate

Tags: winapi, certificate-authority

I have a variable of type PCCERT_CONTEXT which contains a certificate (this is actually the certificate of the digital signer of a given executable file.) I need to get the certificate or at least the name of the issuing CA. I've tried using CertOpenStore and WTHelperCertFindIssuerCertificate, but have had no success. I would appreciate any help.

Regards,

Alireza

Comment: this is a window specific question about the windows API from a C/C++ program, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe CertGetIssuerCertificateFromStore()?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want CertGetCertificateChain http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376078(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The CERT_CONTEXT contains the [CERT_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377200(VS.85).aspx) structure.
The CERT_INFO structure contains a pointer to the Issuer as a CERT_NAME_BLOB.